# Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I'm using Spring and Hibernate in a Java-EE application. The project is hosted at [this GitHub repository](http://github.com/whirlwin/niths).
I'm having problems using `@Autowired through the Service like this:

```
package no.niths.rest;

// Imports ...

@Controller
@RequestMapping("courses")
public class CourseController implements SimpleREST<Course>{

    @Autowired
    public CourseService service;
}
```

And the respectice Service:

```
package no.niths.services;

// Imports ...

@Service
public class CourseService {

    @Autowired
    public ICourse repo;
}
```

And finally my `app-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>/configuration.properties</value>
                </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="no.niths.services"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="no.niths.rest"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="no.niths.infrastructure"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="no.niths.infrastructure.interfaces"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="no.niths.domain"/>


    <import resource="db-config.xml" />
</beans>
```

And the error thrown when deploying is:

**Here is the updated stack trace:**

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'courseController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private no.niths.services.CourseService no.niths.rest.CourseController.service; nested exception is org.springfrainitmework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [no.niths.services.CourseService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private no.niths.services.CourseService no.niths.rest.CourseController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [no.niths.services.CourseService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [no.niths.services.CourseService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 23 more

ERROR | 2012-01-26 15:30:07,999 | ContextLoader.java | 307 | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'courseController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private no.niths.services.CourseService no.niths.rest.CourseController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [no.niths.services.CourseService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private no.niths.services.CourseService no.niths.rest.CourseController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [no.niths.services.CourseService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [no.niths.services.CourseService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
```

What is causing this and what the problem this autowiring?

Comment: Your code isn't correctly compiled, as the error says.  There's no point deploying the app if you can't compile it first.

Comment: Why wouldn't you compile your code first? Not sure I understand the thought process there.

Comment: @skaffman I'm using Eclipse with some kind of continous-integration feature, so the it tries to deploy it (to a SpringFabric server) after Maven has built it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't in the controller or anything, but in some repository classes where I was using `SessionFactory` with `@Autowired`.

Comment: I am also having the same problem with  "SessionFactory", what is the solution?

Comment: @vissupepala Sorry for the really late reply, but I'm actually not sure. The subject is unfortunately poorly documented.

Answer (score 4):

Add the Spring Beans dependency, which contains the org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired  annotation class :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The annotation already seems to be available, we have been using it in some unit tests already, good suggestion though.

Comment: Check if the spring-beans JAR is in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your WAR.

Comment: Yes, I found it: `WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar`.

Comment: Are you using a JVM >= 1.5 on the JEE Server ?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to say it's using `1.7`.

Comment: From the stacktrace, it seems the error comes from your constructor of the CourseController (at no.niths.rest.CourseController.<init>(CourseController.java:20)) but I don't see any constructor in this class...

Comment: Try by updating your spring config file and using only one context component scan with your base package : <context:component-scan base-package="no.niths"/>

Comment: I tried that too, it turns out the problem lies in the classes using `@Autowired` on `SessionFactory`, when they were removed, everything worked as it should, so I am rewriting the project to use `@ComponentScan` instead of XML.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure spring-beans.jar is in your app classpath.

1. In maven you could use 'mvn dependency:tree' to see if this jar is included as dependency
2. When your project is build (WAR I presume) make sure that jar is in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Windows or Unix? On Unix check maximum number of open files limit (ulimit command)

Comment: *nix, and it says `unlimited`.

Comment: Looking at Exception again it clearly says 'Unresolved compilation problem'. Are you invoking code which has been generated by Eclipse? The source was erroneous, so the Eclipse compiler could not compile it - instead byte code has been generated that shows the message in the question.

Comment: I don't know what I did, but the compilation problem is no longer. See the question for more details.